# ESP32 power efficient battery monitoring

Tags: low-power, esp32, battery-operated

I'm trying to implement a simple battery monitoring circuit for an ESP32 that gets completely shut down and then powered on periodically. I don't want to drain the battery and/or backpower the ESP32 while it is turned off.

Here is the circuit that I've put together from looking at what others have done:
[image: switched voltage divider power monitoring circuit]

I know there are better solutions out there (like a fuel gauge IC). I'm just trying to get something basic working. Although, I could be convinced to switch to a proper fuel gauge if everyone tells me this circuit is total garbage.

Basically this is using a transistor to turn on a PFET that connects a voltage divider that is connected to the ESP32 to measure the battery voltage. "3v3_RUN" is my power bus that is powered periodically to provide power to the ESP32 + the rest of the components. The "3V3_RUN" bus power is cut off after all calculations are done.

Questions:

1. Does anyone see any issues with this design?
2. I don't really understand how to choose the correct value resistor for the base of the BC847 transistor. I'm a hobbyist (not a professional EE). When I search for how to size resistors for a transistor as a switch, it talks about knowing what the current of the load is. In my case would that be the mosfet drain current? I'm pretty lost here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You’re using Q201 to switch a FET, and not at high speed, so the current you need to be able to provide will be tiny.  R204 pulls the gate up to switch the FET off, and this can be quite large (100k would be fine).  R203 needs to provide enough current to ensure that Q201 is switched fully on when needed.  The key here is that bipolar transistors have a characteristic called ‘current gain’ or Hfe, which describes how the collector current that the transistor allows to flow is proportional to the vase current (although not very proportional in practice).  For small-signal transistors this is often about 100, so if you provide say 1mA into the base then the transistor will conduct up to 100mA at the collector.  Therefore your base resistor should be somewhat less than 100 times the value of R204.  We tend not to use super-high resistor values as these are quite sensitive to noise, moisture etc so 470k or 1M would be a good choice here.  That means that when the circuit is switched on you’ll get a few uA through the base and a few 10s of uA through R204, then whatever current your voltage monitor itself draws.

Comment: I'm not clear on how to provide 1mA to the base in relation to what you said. To provide 1mA at the base wouldn't I figure out the resistor value with R=V/I (3.3v/.001A = 3.3KOhm)? I'm sure I'm wrong, just not connecting the dots :-)

Comment: Almost, the base-emitter voltage will be about 600mV so 2.7k would provide 1mA.  You’re on the right track though.

Comment: If the base resistor needs to be 2.7k to provide 1mA, what is the significance of the 470k - 1M resistor that you said would be a good choice?

Comment: The work that Q201 and R204 need to do is to switch the FET, which requires a tiny amount of energy and so R204 can be quite large, eg 1M so it will only draw a few uA when switched on.  If we make a pessimistic guess that the Hfe of Q201 is 10 (more likely it’s 100) then we need to supply a few hundred nA into the base.  If we supply more current than that then it does no harm except that it’s wasted energy.  If we use 1M for R202 and R203 then the current here will again be a few uA which is ample.  The 2.7k would provide 1mA to the base but you don’t need that much current.

Comment: I mentioned the 1mA figure as an example of how current gain works in a bipolar transistor, that figure isn’t relevant to this particular circuit.

Comment: Ah ok this is making sense! Your original suggestion for this circuit was to use a 100k resistor for R204, and 1M for R203. In one of your more recent comments it sounds like you recommend the R202 pull-down to also be a 1M. What’s the reason for that? Versus say 100k?

Comment: The benefit of a larger resistor is that it draws less current, the downside is that switching is slower and it’s more sensitive to noise, humidity etc.  100k and 1M are both reasonable values, it just depends on your priorities, whether you want a super-robust design or you’re scraping the last few uA